# "Махайте на меня, махайте!"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Допустимо ли в русском языке слово "махайте" или вариант "машите" единственный?
*Просто, сразу вспомнилась фраза Змеюкиной из "Свадьбы".*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то до относительно недавнего времени именно вариант "махайте" считался единсвенным правильным. Сейчас норма сместилась, нормативным считается "машите", но "махайте" по-прежнему возможно как минимум на уровне разговорного (в уровне нормативности словари несколькоко расходятся).

Кстати, учтите ещё, что у "махать" есть второе, сугубо разговорное, значение. "Отмахать" - пройти (Семь верст отмахали). В этом значении - только "махаю, махайте", формы с "ш" невозможны в принципе.